# Setting context from child causes infinite call loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, use-context

I have an application that uses `react-router-dom`.

```js
// App.js
function App() {
    return (
        <SiteContextProvider>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/player/:slug"><PlayerPage /></Route>
                <Route default><NotFoundPage /></Route>
            </Switch>
        </SiteContextProvider>
        );
}
```

The PlayerPage child component sets the SiteContext to the value of the parameter `slug` passed in the URL.

```js
// SiteContextProvider.js
export const SiteContext = React.createContext(null);

export function SiteContextProvider(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

    return <SiteContext.Provider value={{value, setValue}}>{props.children}</SiteContext.Provider>;
}
```

```js
export function PlayerPage(props) {
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const { value, setValue } = useContext(SiteContext);
    setValue(slug);

    return <span>{value}</span>;
}
```

The problem is that when `PlayerPage` loads, it calls `setValue`, which sets the value of the context, reloading `PlayerPage`. This causes an infinite loop and my code crashes. How do I make PlayerPage set the value of the context only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
export function PlayerPage(props) {
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const { value, setValue } = useContext(SiteContext);
    // Don't call setValue directly inside the function
    setValue(slug);

    return <span>{value}</span>;
}
```

This makes the context state change -> rerender this component which will change the state again -> rerender this component etc.

instead you should call it inside an effect:

```
export function PlayerPage(props) {
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const { value, setValue } = useContext(SiteContext);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setValue(slug);
    }, [slug, setValue]);

    return <span>{value}</span>;
}
```